# How to Detect forward and reply contents in email body in Email python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and i want to detect the forward and reply contents in email body of received email using python.
And i also want to detect and remove the signature from that email in python.How can i detect and remove that contents using python.

Comment: you wont get any help here if you havent got any code

Comment: imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host,port)
imap.login(user, passwd)
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
res, email_data = imap.fetch(latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email_string =  email_data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
for part in email_message.walk():if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
This is my code and i get all body contents form the mail along with forward message contents and signature & i need only message not other contents like signature and forward info.